# How to dereference only hash of hash of array in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

```
{    
    'A' =>      ['B'], //hash of array   
    'C' => {'D' => [  'E']} //hash of hash of array    
}
```

When try to parse hash of hash of array. getting **"Not a HASH reference"** error. Even I tried used exists and defined keywords to avoid this error. But result is same error.

From above i need to only iterate hash of hash of array.

```
foreach my $keys (keys %$hash){
        print "$keys";
     if (defined $hash->{$keys}->{maptype}){
            foreach my $array_element ( @{$hash->{$keys}->{'D'}} ) {
                        print "$array_element"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are written with `#` in Perl, not with `//`.

Comment: What is "maptype"?  If you are checking to see if a hash key's value is a reference you need to use [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is best practice, but:

```
my $hash = { A => ['B'], C => {D => ['E'], F => [qw(G H I)]}, J=>42 };

for my $key (keys %$hash) {
    if (ref $hash->{$key} eq 'HASH') {
        for my $subkey (keys %{$hash->{$key}}) {
            say "$key => $subkey => [", join(",", @{$hash->{$key}{$subkey}}), "]";
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
C => D => [E]
C => F => [G,H,I]
```

Comment: When I have to deal with an inconsistent structure (ie. where all 'things' inside of another thing might not be the same), I've found this to be the easiest way.